# is it good to cache from .each method?

Tags: jquery, caching

I want to do something like this:

```
cache = [];
jQuery("#selector1 .class").each(function(index, item) {
    cache.push({'index': index, 'item': item});
});
```

the problem is, if I later `console.log` them, it seems good, still this not works: `jQuery(cache[0].item).fadeOut();` but no error message takes place.
But since there are object, I think the caching method itself is bad. So we store an object which is locally given in that `.each` function. Of course that item disappears someday, only its reference remains. How to store that object then?

Comment: Weird. Theoretically this should work. Lemme try.

Comment: and theoretically storing references is not good, since the object behind it can be disposed any time

Comment: What you have should (and does) work fine. However this seems largely redundant as you can already access the elements in the DOM by index. There's very few ways I can see this added complexity being of any worthwhile benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just tried it and tried to log the `item` that's stored. It perfectly works this way:

```js
$(function () {
  var cache = [];
  $("ul li").each(function (index, item) {
    cache.push({'index': index, 'item': item});
  });
  $(cache[0].item).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually this fadeOut doesnt happen right after caching, but a bit later, in an event :)

Comment: You could use `map()` instead of `each()`, but I don't believe there's any performance difference, it's just more succinct.